# java.lang.NullPointerException in session factory building hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, session, sessionfactory, hibernate-4.x

I am simply trying to create a session factory object in hibernate 4. It throws null pointer exception while creating session factory object.

**Hibernate configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@SHKG9072DB:5030:TMSD10G2</property>
<property name="connection.username">ICTDEV$EDI_APP</property>
<property name="connection.password">p2II9JLIaea06</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<property name="format_sql">true</property>


<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> 

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Code to create session factory**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Trying to create a test connection with the database.");
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
}
```

**Logs**

```
Trying to create a test connection with the database.
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM  org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
May 20, 2015 5:04:55 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  getConfigurationInputStream
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntityINFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@SHKG9072DB:5030:TMSD10G2]
 May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=ICTDEV$EDI_APP, password=****}
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl configure
WARN: HHH000341: Could not obtain connection metadata : Unsupported feature
May 20, 2015 5:04:56 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
  INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:244)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at com.world.demo.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try adding these properties in xml file:

name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"
   name = "hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation" ="true"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hibernate-hikaricp, this can happen if you do not set the connection provider class:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
hibernate.hikari.jdbcUrl=...
```